# Minimal ideal in the Affine Dimension Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y,Z$ be affine  varieties (irreducible). Then every irreducible components $W$ of $Y \cap Z$ correspends to the *minimal* prime ideals $\frak{p}$ of the principal ideal $(f)$. **Why can we say that it is "minimal" ideal?**

Because $Y \subset Z$ we obtain $Y \cap Z  \subset Z$. Thus, for any irreducible component $W_i$ of $Y\cap Z$, we get $ W_i \subset Y \cap Z  \subset Z$.

$I(W_i) \supset I(Y \cap Z)   \supset I(Z)=\sqrt{(f)}=(f)$.

Thus

$I(W_i) \supset  (f)$.

But I cannot understand where the word "*minimal*" appears?

In the following proof of the statement(Hartshorne page 48 Prop 7.1), the *minimal* prime ideal is used, but I cannot understand how it is used.

> **Prop** Let $YU,Z$ be varieties of dimension $r,s$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Then every irreducible component $W$ of $Y\cap Z$ has dimension $\geq
>  r+s-n$.
>
> PROOF. We proceed in several steps. First, suppose that $Z$ is a hyper
>   surface, defined by an equation $f=0$. If $Y \subset Z$, there is
>   nothing to prove. If $Y  \nsubseteq Z$, we must show that each
>   irreducible component $W$ of $Y\cap Z$ has dimension $r-1$. Let $A(Y)$
>   be the affine coordinate ring of $Y$. Then the irreducible components
>   of $Y\cap Z$ correspond to the minimal prime ideals $\frak{p}$ of the
>   principal ideal $(f)$ in  $A(Y)$. Now by Krull's Hauptidealsatz, each
>   such $\frak{p}$ has height one, so by the dimension theorem,
>   $A(Y)/\frak{p}$ has dimension $r-1$. Because the dimesnion of $W$ is
>   the dimension of its affine coordinate ring, $W$ has dimesnion $r-1$. 
>   PROOF is continued for $Z$ is not a hyper surface case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the inclusion-reversing bijection between ideals and varieties. Under the dictionary between the ideal side and the variety side, an irreducible subvariety corresponds to a prime ideal cutting it out, and a containment of varieties $X\subset Y$ corresponds to a containment of ideals $I_X\supset I_Y$. As an irreducible component is maximal with respect to containment among irreducible subvarieties, when we apply this correspondence, it gets transformed in to a prime ideal minimal with respect to containment among prime ideals, aka a minimal prime.

Comment: @JeanBillie is there a reason you've accepted the answer but not upvoted it?

Comment: The statement of the theorem just spells out as "varieties". However every result it uses is relevant on "affine varieties". Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: @Siddhartha If you're talking about the statement in the post ("let $Y,Z$ be varieties in $\Bbb A^n$") what it really means is that $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subvarieties of $\Bbb A^n$, which means that they are affine varieties. I don't think there's anything interesting going on here - Hartshorne probably just forgot it or is using a standard assumption that he's not reminding the readers of.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the first part goes through while $Y$ is quasi-affine and $Z$ is a hyper surface by the usual ${\mathrm{dim}}~Y = {\mathrm{dim}}~{\overline{Y}}$ and the fact closure w.r.t. $Z$ coincides with closure w.r.t. ${\mathbb{A}}^n$. This made it confusing. In the second part of the proof the product works only for affine varieties.

Comment: I mean, it's still true that all irreducible components of $Y\cap Z$ are of the required codimension when $Y,Z$ are quasi-affine: just use the fact that $Y$ and $Z$ are open in their closure, so $Y=U\cap \overline{Y}$ and $Z=V\cap \overline{Z}$ where $U,V$ are open in $\Bbb A^n$. Then $Y\cap Z$ can be written as $U\cap V$, an open subset, intersect  $\overline{Y}\cap\overline{Z}$, and then one can conclude the desired result from the fact that a nonempty open subset of an irreducible variety has the same dimension. It may happen that some components disappear, but that's ok!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the clarification. :)